# Nativescript Swipe/Carousel Example

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am thinking to implement the swipe/slide function (horizontally) onto a page with multiple elements on the screen. Tried verticalScroll but it is not what sliders do as they have a fixed position. There is a plugin nativescript-carousel but it has got a few limitation and allows only one element on the screen at a time.

Is there any real example for iOS and Android available or has anyone created it with vanilla JS?

Thank you for your help and ideas.